# MS Word VBA script to add Bookmarks to Existing Content Controls

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2007

I have over 150 Content Control (CC) boxes within a document and was wondering if someone would be able to help me with VBA script to add bookmarks to them programmatically. The names for the new bookmarks  would have to match the Title or Tags I've inserted for the CCs. For example, if I have a CC in the document with the title 'TestResults' I'd like the bookmark called 'TestResults' to be inserted on that CC.  I'm an absolute beginner to VB!

So I guess I want the code to do the following:

1. Find all the CCs in the document and their titles
2. Insert bookmarks matching the CC title.

Comment: What type of content Control box are you using? Either a rich text or plain text box (I want to assume)?

Comment: Sorry I couldn't answer this earlier...you solved this anyway. Yes, they were rich text CCs. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
Sub AddBookmarksAtCC()
    Dim ccobjA As ContentControl, i As Integer
    For i = 1 To ActiveDocument.ContentControls.Count
        Set ccobjA = ActiveDocument.ContentControls.Item(i)
        Debug.Print ccobjA.Title
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add ccobjA.Title, ActiveDocument.ContentControls.Item(i).Range
    Next i
End Sub
```

This procedure will count all Content Controls on the document, and loop though them all, adding a bookmark at each one. As it is, the bookmark will be named the title of the content control. If you want to make it the Tag, replace `ccobjA.Title` with `ccobjA.Tag`.
Let me know if you are still having trouble.

Comment: Hi Kyle, Thank you SO much, that worked like a charm! You just saved me hours of work, God bless you!